# alert notification(Local) weird behaviour when fired from didEnterRegion

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, ibeacon, clregion

When i was testing my application today, i realised that when the notification fired from didEnterRegion did not managed to trigger the below code..  ( I set the notification to Alert Notification)

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
if (notification)
{
//Set rootViewController.
}
```

However , when i changed the notification style to banner style. The above code did triggered

Code for enter region:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region{

[self sendLocalNotificationForReqgionConfirmationWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Check out %@ latest offer today!!", region.identifier]forBeaconRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region];}


-(void)sendLocalNotificationForReqgionConfirmationWithText:(NSString *)text forBeaconRegion: (CLBeaconRegion *)region {
NSNumber *testValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:100];
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotif.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:1.0 sinceDate:[NSDate date]];
localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotif.alertBody = @"test";
localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
localNotif.userInfo = @{@"Major": testValue };

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
[_locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:region];}
```

So, can anyone can enlighten me of what is the error? Or at least provide me some direction. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Local Notification can be viewed as an alertView when the app is in foreground.... Check Airlocate of Apple

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. But my App is in the background when i launch the application via notification. So, if I'm not wrong, the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions will be called right.

Comment: if you want to detect the local notification that was tapped to open your app, then application-didReceiveLocalNotification delegate is the method to be called

Comment: I'm so sorry about the previous replay. what i mean is that my application is not running in both background and foreground. So, didReceiveLocalNotification still will get called? Let me go give it a try. :)